# jsf login times out

Tags: jsf, authentication, viewexpiredexception

Ok simple question. I have a JSF application, containing a login page. The problem is if the user loads the login page, leaves it for a while, then tries to login the session expires and a ViewExpiredException is thrown. I could redirect back to the login when this happens, but that isn't very smooth. How can I allow this flow to properly login without an additional attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

As of Mojarra 2.1.19 / 2.2.0 you can now set the transient attribute of the `<f:view>` to true:

```
<f:view transient="true">
     Your regular content
</f:view>
```

You can read about in on [Balusc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)  blog here:

http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/stateless-jsf.html

**Original**

If you're using Facelets you can create your own ViewHandler to handle this:

```
public class LoginViewHandler extends FaceletViewHandler
{
    public LoginViewHandler( ViewHandler viewHandler )
    {
        super( viewHandler );
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot restoreView( FacesContext ctx, String viewId )
    {
        UIViewRoot viewRoot = super.restoreView( ctx, viewId );

        if ( viewRoot == null && viewId.equals( "/login.xhtml" ) )
        {
            // Work around Facelet issue
            initialize( ctx );

            viewRoot = super.createView( ctx, viewId );
            ctx.setViewRoot( viewRoot );

            try
            {
                buildView( ctx, viewRoot );
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                log.log( Level.SEVERE, "Error building view", e ); 
            }
        }

        return viewRoot;
    }
}
```

Change "/login.xhtml" to your login page.  This checks to see if it can restore your view, and if it cannot and the current view is your login page it will create and build the view for you.

Set this in your face-config.xml as follows:

```
<application>
    <!-- snip -->
    <view-handler>my.package.LoginViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

If you're using JSF without Facelets (i.e. JSPs) you can try having the class extend ViewHandlerWrapper - note that buildView() will not be available.  Hopefully createView() on it's own will set the view up correctly but I'm not 100% sure with JSF/JSP.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in JSF 2?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your login page is in session scope, when it really doesn't need to be.  Request scope should be fine for a login page (since, realistically there shouldn't be anything in session before the user logs in).  Once the user logs in, you may have this issue crop back up, but Phill's ideas are very good from there on.

Answer (score 0):

With jsp you can disable the session for a page including this directive `<%@ page session="false" %>`. There must be something similar for jsf.

Answer (score -1):

Couple of slightly hacky solutions:

- (Very hacky) use a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/>` tag to automatically reload the page every so often.
- Use a JavaScript function to periodically send a 'ping' request to the server to keep the session alive.

We use [IceFaces](http://www.icefaces.org) at work which automatically detects when your session has expired and displays a pop-up alerting you to the fact. But we do still sometimes have problems on the login page for some reason.