# IceFaces Session Expiry causes an exception

Tags: jsf, icefaces, session-timeout

My IceFaces application crashes on session expiry. It's not showing the "User Session Expired" or "Network Connection Interrupted" message.

My guess is the same page is loaded again, and since the backing bean code cannot find the session variables, it throws the following exception:

```
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /main-template.jspx: User session has expired or it was invalidated.

root cause
java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /main-template.jspx: User session has expired or it was invalidated.

root cause
javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /main-template.jspx: User session has expired or it was invalidated.

root cause
javax.el.ELException: /main-template.jspx: User session has expired or it was invalidated.

root cause
com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SessionExpiredException: User session has expired or it was invalidated.

root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC2778: getAttribute: Session already invalidated
```

Asynchronous updates are on, and the jsp page has the `<ice:outputConnectionStatus />` component.

Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?

**Note**: I was doing a lot of fancy stuff, like redirecting on session timeout, and displaying error pages for java.lang.Throwable, but I've commented it all out - without luck. When both redirection and error-handling were switched on, on the first time the application would show the error page, then after a while redirect to "session-expiry" page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with RichFaces and this answer saved me :

[jsf login times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231191/jsf-login-times-out)

For a lot of turn around and stranges things I recommend to see this blog :

http://balusc.blogspot.com/

Here is the code I'm currently using :

```
package com.spectotechnologies.jsf.viewhandler;

import com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandler;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/**
 * Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231191/jsf-login-times-out
 *
 * This ViewHandler is used to remove the ViewExpiredException problem at login
 * after the session is expired.
 *
 * @author Alexandre Lavoie
 */
public class AutoRegeneratorViewHandler extends FaceletViewHandler
{
    public AutoRegeneratorViewHandler(ViewHandler p_oViewHandler)
    {
        super(p_oViewHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext p_oContext, String p_sViewID)
    {
        UIViewRoot oViewRoot = super.restoreView(p_oContext,p_sViewID);

        if(oViewRoot == null)
        {
            // Work around Facelet issue
            initialize(p_oContext);

            oViewRoot = super.createView(p_oContext,p_sViewID);
            p_oContext.setViewRoot(oViewRoot);

            try
            {
                buildView(p_oContext,oViewRoot);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return oViewRoot;
    }
}
```

You also have to put this in faces-config.xml :

```
<application>
    <view-handler>com.spectotechnologies.jsf.viewhandler.AutoRegeneratorViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've already implemented it using a hack involving a custom Error 500 page (which is obviously the wrong way). I'll try to implement this method later.